# Do I need to adjust the truss rod when I change string gauge

Tags: electric-guitar, maintenance, string-gauge

I am changing the string gauge of my electric guitar from 9's to 10's, will I need to adjust the truss rod, if so could anyone recommend tutorials ?

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say categorically yes or no, until you put the .009s on, and allow a few days for settlement. The change in tension is less than 10%, and the guitar's neck may well not move at all. Simplest is to measure some dimensions before and after - string height at 12th fret is a must, and feel playability after - you may not notice any difference. The make and model (and age) of the guitar are also factors that are relevant.

A more crucial factor is checking intonation, which will be slightly affected anyway. There are many sources of info. as to how this is achieved, along with how to remedy it. Actually, recommendations of this kind don't sit well on this site.